# How do I compile SCSS files recursively in folder tree?

Tags: css, command-line, compilation, sass

I have a complex folder tree where every folder contains several SCSS files. I want to compile them into CSS recursively, all at one time. What command line tool and parameters should I use to do that?

Comment: Try using the --watch option with the sass command like so:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the --watch option with the sass command like so: `sass --watch directory` this will compile and watch the source files for changes.